# Elasticsearch Updating field value issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to work with `update_by_query` but cannot make it work.

Following is a simple query,

```
curl -X GET "172.17.0.3:9200/useripvsuserid/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "_source":"userid","query": {
    "term": {
      "userip": "10.0.30.181"
    }
  }
}
'
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 10.803431,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "useripvsuserid",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PhfBW3AB8mhGfmGvIs-j",
        "_score" : 10.803431,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : "hasan1855"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Following is the `update_by_query` that is not working. I am trying to replace `userid` value `hasan1855` to `arif`. Where is the problem?

```
curl -X POST "172.17.0.3:9200/useripvsuserid/_update_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "script": {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "source": "ctx._source.userid='arif';",
    "lang": "painless"       
  }, 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "userip": "10.0.30.181"
    }
  }
}
'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "ctx._source.userid=arif;",
          "                   ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "ctx._source.userid=arif;",
        "lang" : "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "compile error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "ctx._source.userid=arif;",
      "                   ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : "ctx._source.userid=arif;",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Variable [arif] is not defined."
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60281407/4604579), i.e. the single quotes around `arif` conflict with the single quotes around the JSON query.

So you can either send your query in binary mode as explained in the link above, or escape the quotes, like this:

```
curl -X POST "172.17.0.3:9200/useripvsuserid/_update_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "script": {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "source": "ctx._source.userid = \"arif\";",         <---- escape quotes
    "lang": "painless"       
  }, 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "userip": "10.0.30.181"
    }
  }
}
'
```